# How to get the URL from local files?

Tags: python, html, url

I used Wget to download webpages.
I want to ask "Is it possible to get the URL from local html files?"

I used python to analysis the html file content. I want to print all files' URL.

I am trying to add more functions on this program, so I think if I can print the URL follow result, then user can easy click link to get the webpage.

Here is my code:

```
    def search(self):
        keyword = self.entry.get()
        mypath = "/Users/Tsu-AngChou/MasterProject/Practice/try_test/"
        files = listdir(mypath)

        translator = str.maketrans("","",string.punctuation)

        count1 = 0
        test_list = []
        test_list2 = []

        for f in files:
            fullpath = join(mypath, f)

            if f == '.DS_Store':
                            os.remove(f)
            elif isfile(fullpath):

#           print(f)

                for html_cont in range(1):
                    response = open(f,'r',encoding='utf-8')
                    html_cont = response.read()
                    soup = bs(html_cont, 'html.parser')
                    regular_string = soup.get_text()
                    new_string = regular_string.translate(translator).split()
                    new_list = [item[:14] for item in new_string]
                    a = dict.fromkeys(new_list, f)

                    wordfreq = []
                    c = new_list
                    for w in c:
                        wordfreq.append(c.count(w))
                        fre = dict(zip(c,wordfreq))               

                    sentence= new_list
                    keyword1= keyword
                    words = sentence

                    if keyword in fre:
                        test_list.append(a[keyword])
                        test_list2.append(fre[keyword])

                        count1 = count1+1

                        for (i, subword) in enumerate(words):
                            if (subword == keyword1): 
                                test_list3= i+1




        for i in range(0,count1-1):
            for j in range(0,count1-1-i):
                if (test_list2[j]<test_list2[j+1]):
                    temp=test_list[j]
                    temp2=test_list2[j]

                    test_list[j]=test_list[j+1]
                    test_list2[j]=test_list2[j+1]

                    test_list[j+1]=temp
                    test_list2[j+1]=temp2


        for i in range(0,count1):
            print(keyword, "Filename:", test_list[i], "Frequency:", test_list2[i])

        return a
```

[This is my output, and I want to have the link follow every result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aKY7.png)

Comment: Please add an example as well as the code you have tried.

Comment: What did you, yet? And what do you expect? And how do you think this might work? -- We are helping, not teaching

Comment: HTML files don't contain information about their origin i.e. from which URL they were downloaded. You'd need to save the URL and file path in some way as each file is downloaded.

Comment: @Mark so I have to find others way to save the URL? Do you know any other ways? I have no idea about this...

Comment: I'm not sure what the best approach would be, but you could create a dictionary with file paths/names as keys and URLs as values. Since you must know the URL in order to download the file, just use the same URL you pass to wget and then add a new entry to the dictionary. `wget.download` returns the file name.